# Badge proposal: asleep at the wheel

Tags: feature-request, badges

I think it would be kind of cool to have a badge for gaining at least a certain amount of reputation between the end of a 24-hour period of no activity and the next activity. That is, if I were active on the site at 9:00 Monday, then at 9:00 Tuesday the counter would start. It would stop when I was next active, and I'd get a badge if it came over a certain number.

Comment: This one is weird. On the other hand, it happens that some answers don't get upvotes at first, then after some time people come and vote. A badge commenting how "a genius idea might be only appreciated from perspective of time" or something similar would be funny. A badge would be given if user gained more than $X$ reputation by votes newer than the last edit of the answer by some specific amount of time (a week, month, whatever). Isn't this a similar idea to yours?

Comment: I like the OP's idea (but perhaps a different name)... it would recognize people like [Arturo](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin) who have earned a lot of reputation even though they haven't been active.

Comment: @dtldarek: that's the general idea, yes. The tricky thing is that it's possible to draw attention to your own earlier post by linking to it in a comment or answer elsewhere. I'm not saying my way is absolutely *better*, but it is perhaps better in that way. Neither prevents anyone from intentionally gaming the system via sock-puppets, of course.

Comment: Asleep at the wheel sounds a little dangerous.  How about `Livin' On The Dividends`, or simply `Mogul`?  Further, I propose the conditions of the badge be something like "Earned over 200 reputation during a 24 hour period of inactivity no less than 24 hours since last login," to prevent giving a good answer, going to sleep, then coming back the next day with the badge.  (So, somebody would have to be logged out for at least a day before breaking the rep cap.)